# Babel, Maximum call stack size exceeded while using path.replaceWith

Tags: babeljs, babylonjs, stack-size

I was trying to play with babel modules, `babylon`, `babel-traverse`. When I tried to replace a node, the program crashed with `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Here is my code

```
import * as babylon from 'babylon'
import traverse from 'babel-traverse'
import generate from 'babel-generator'
import * as t from 'babel-types'


const code = `
import a from 'b'
n === 3
`
const ast = babylon.parse(code, {
  sourceType: 'module'
})

const visitor = {
  BinaryExpression(path) {
    console.log((path.node))
    path.replaceWith(t.binaryExpression('**', t.numericLiteral(3), t.numericLiteral(4)))
  }
}

traverse(ast, visitor)

let generated = generate(ast, null, code)
console.log(generated.code)
```

And I'am using below babel dependencies, any idea?

```
"dependencies": {
"babel-generator": "^6.9.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
"babel-traverse": "^6.9.0",
"babel-types": "^6.9.1",
"babylon": "^6.8.0"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding the new binaryExpression while you have a visitor on BinaryExpression causes the new binaryExpression to be visited, and so it is an infinite loop. You can call [`path.skip`](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#stopping-traversal) after `path.replaceWith` to skip visiting the new expression.

```
path.replaceWith(t.binaryExpression('**', t.numericLiteral(3), t.numericLiteral(4)))
path.skip()
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason you're getting a stack error is because your binary expression replacement generates another binary expression. Your replacement binary expression is fed into the visitor over and over again, ad infinitum.

To break the infinite loop, you need to check whether your replacement has already occurred, possibly by ignoring the `replaceWith` step whenever you see the operator is `**`.